# What is the correct way to label columns in a tensorflow dataset when imported from unlabeled csv?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, tensorflow

### Question and MWE

I have some data in a csv file without labeled headers such as: `labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` on the columns.  I am using Numpy to import the data into a Tensorflow dataset.  My MWE looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.loadtxt("csvfile.csv", delimiter=',', dtype="uint32"), dtype=tf.uint32)
```

When I look at the output from `dataset`, I see what I expect:

```
<tf.Tensor: id=2, shape=(1545, 4), dtype=uint32, numpy=
array([[    68,    442,    730,  40000],
       [    71,    857,    609, 150000],
       [    71,    857,    609, 110000],
       ...,
       [   295,    615,    145,  50000],
       [   297,    443,    854,  10000],
       [   298,    541,    309,  20000]], dtype=uint32)>
```

What is the best way to label these columns at this point in the script?

### Obvious Answer Which Doesn't Work

I do not want to edit the CSV file before starting my python code, *e.g. manually inserting headers on 4 columns*.  In my case, I cannot assume that I will always be able to access the CSV file.

### What I Tried

I attempted to tack headers onto the top of the numpy object with:

```
fff = np.loadtxt("csvfile.csv", delimiter=',', dtype="uint32")
fff = np.vstack((np.array(("a", "b", "c", "d")), fff))
dataset = convert_to_tensor(fff, dtype=tf.uint32)
```

But that obviously fails due to mixed encoding.

Comment: IIC, the `Tensor` object does not have a labels property: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor.  If you want labels, perhaps a `Variable` object might work.  See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable).

Comment: Does that mean that the generators in the Image Classification tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#load_data) automatically import into `Variable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a dictionary without altering the original data.  In this case:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

fff = np.loadtxt("csvfile.csv", delimiter=',', dtype="uint32")
mydict = {"a": fff[:, 0], "b": fff[:, 1], "c": fff[:, 2], "d": fff[:, 3]}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((mydict["a"], mydict["b"], mydict["c"], mydict["d"]))
```

Data can be inspected by iterating through the nested tensor:

```
for i in dataset:
    print(i[0].numpy()) #prints the "a" entry
```